# tkinter - canvas with scroll bar AND bg image

Tags: canvas, tkinter, background, scrollbar, python-3.4

My goal here is to create a canvas, wich as a bg image, and inside it has a  frame wich contains various labels (the number of the labels can grow), and to simulate it I created a frame with a bigger size than the canvas, but as u can see, when you use the scrollbar the bg image moves too.
How can I move just whats inside the canvas WITHOUT moving the background image? is that even possible?

```
 def pr_onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

from tkinter import *

_F_CassaCenter = Tk()


#Master Frame to hold the canvas and scrollbar
_F_CarrelloMain = LabelFrame(_F_CassaCenter, text = "Window")
_F_CarrelloMain.pack()

#Canvas
_C_Maincanvas = Canvas(_F_CarrelloMain, width = 450, height = 300)
_C_Maincanvas.pack(side="left")
_C_Maincanvas.pack_propagate(False)


#Canvas Background image
bgimage = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\bg.png")
_C_Maincanvas.create_image(225,150,image = bgimage)
_C_Maincanvas.image_names()

#ScrollBar
_S_Carrello = Scrollbar(_F_CarrelloMain, orient="vertical", command=_C_Maincanvas.yview)
_S_Carrello.pack(side="left", fill="y")
_C_Maincanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=_S_Carrello.set)


#Inside the canvas
_F_OuterCarrelloInner = Frame(_C_Maincanvas, bg="orange")
_F_OuterCarrelloInner.pack()

_F_CarrelloInner = Frame(_F_OuterCarrelloInner, width = 100, height = 350,bg = "green")
_F_CarrelloInner.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
_F_CarrelloInner.pack_propagate(False)

#Canvas internal window to hold stuff that will grow
_C_Maincanvas.create_window((225, 150), window = _F_OuterCarrelloInner)
_F_OuterCarrelloInner.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=_C_Maincanvas:     pr_onFrameConfigure(_C_Maincanvas))



_F_CassaCenter.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

I attached this function to the scrollbar but it moves the inner frames to the right of the canvas

```
def custom_yview(*args, **kwargs):
    _C_Maincanvas.yview(*args, **kwargs)
    x = _C_Maincanvas.canvasx(225)
    y = _C_Maincanvas.canvasy(150)
    _C_Maincanvas.coords("background", x,y)
```

Comment: I searched `[tkinter] canvas background image` to find the duplicate.  I believe I remember another one more recently.

Comment: I updated the original question with some example code.

Comment: I updated the question